# Raspberry Pi4 4gb built-in Wi-Fi module, hardware or software?

Tags: wifi

Expensive time of day.
For 3D printing I used a Raspberry Pi4 with Klipper installed.
Wi-Fi worked, not always stable, but it worked.
Two weeks later the Wi-Fi was completely disabled. Raspberry does not see the built-in WiFi module and naturally ignores all commands when trying to configure it. Through the LAN cable everything works 100% perfectly, Bluetooth is also weak, but it works.
There was no overheating, the temperature did not rise above 40 degrees, the work intensity was low, a maximum of 15 hours a week.
Maybe it will help someone, I tried a lot of advice from the network, to no avail.
I'm thinking of sending it back under warranty for repair or replacement if it doesn't work again.
Out of the box, wifi worked without any dances with a tambourine.
I understand that there is an alternative - a Wi-Fi flash drive, but I want to understand whether the reason for the failure is hardware or software. If Wi-Fi and Bluetooth are on the same module, will everything fail or am I wrong?
Maybe someone can tell me what to do, I'm not particularly good at this.

Comment: send it back ...

Comment: Seems unlikely but as you have provided no information or diagnostics any answer could only be speculation.

Comment: have you tried a fresh install of a base raspberry pi OS image? that would be the obvious first step

Comment: thanks for the answers, I contacted the seller and sent it back for diagnostics